# opening and closing NAO's hand

Tags: ros, nao-robot, nao-driver, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to open and close NAO's gripper. I searched the documentations but I could not find what command or what topic to publish on to access the robots grippers.

I want to make NAO hold a paper plate in his hand.

Can somebody please tell me how I can open and close NAO's hand through ROS?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188080/opening-and-closing-nao%27s-hand/) by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2014-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The hand is just another joint that can be controlled by publishing a message to the topic "/joint_angles" to which nao_controller node is subscribed. The message type you need is [nao_msgs/JointAnglesWithSpeed](http://docs.ros.org/api/nao_msgs/html/msg/JointAnglesWithSpeed.html)

In this message, you have to put the names of the joint you need in the list "joint_names".  For your case that would be "RHand" or "LHand" as described on [Naoqi's documentation](https://community.aldebaran.com/doc/1-14/family/robots/joints_robot.html#robot-joints-v4-right-arm-joints)

In "joint_angles" I guess it should be either 0 or 1 for open or close hand. "speed" is up to you and "relative" can be set to 0

The final message for opening the right hand with maximal speed would look like this:

```
hand_pos = JointAnglesWithSpeed()
hand_pos.joint_names.append('RHand')
hand_pos.joint_angles.append(1.0)
hand_pos.speed = 1.0
hand_pos.relative = 0
```

Then just publish it to /joint_angles. You should also not forget importing JointAnglesWithSpeed from nao_msgs.msg

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0